# EF6 Dbcontext.SaveChanges works from development machine but fails when published

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two repository functions for adding and removing favorite products for a customer.

```
public void AddProductToCustomer(int customerId, int productId) {
    var customer = _customers.GetById(customerId, 
      new []{ModelContents.FavoriteProducts});
    var product = _products.GetById(productId);
    customer.FavoriteProducts.Add(product);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

and

```
public void RemoveProductFromCustomer(int customerId, int productId) {
    var customer = _customers.GetById(customerId, 
        new[] { ModelContents.FavoriteProducts });
    var product = _products.GetById(productId);
    customer.FavoriteProducts.Remove(product);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I run locally against the production database it works fine but once I publish the code the `_context.SaveChanges()` fails to update the database. I have debugged this code remotely and there is no error thrown or returned from the function. Has anyone else seen this behavior before?

[UPDATE] By fails I mean that the database is not updated with the changes to `customer.FavoriteProducts`. Products are not added or removed from the list respectively and the total count of FavoriteProducts never changes, but only when the code is published, not when I am running it on my dev machine against the same database.

I hope that helps

[UPDATE] It occurred to me that people might wonder what the line `new []{ModelContents.FavoriteProducts}` refers to. This is a enumeration that tells the customer repository which navigation properties to populate for the model. The Customer is a large object and I don't always want all of its data. I have verified that `customer.FavoriteProducts` is populated in these cases.

[UPDATE] One thing that might be related to the issue is that the Product Model also has a `Product.FavoritedBy` Navigation Collection that contains the number of Customers that have Favorited that Product. Just like `Customer.FavoriteProducts` it is always up-to-date when I add or remove from a Customers FavoriteProducts collection except after the application is published to the server. The Entity Relationship is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomerUser>()
            .HasMany(u => u.FavoriteProducts)
            .WithMany(f => f.FavoritedBy)
            .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("UserId")
                .MapRightKey("ProductId")
                .ToTable("FavoriteProducts"));
```

Comment: If the code isn't throwing any exceptions, it's most likely it's writing to a different database from the one you're checking.

Comment: It is definitely writing to the same database. I've quadruple-checked. All of my other repositories are working absolutely fine (there are 11 of them)

Comment: Well then the cause is in code you didn't show. I'm not sure what we can do here, the code you show should work, unless you're doing something strange in code you didn't show. In remove, does `customer.FavoriteProducts.Contains(product)`?

Comment: I don't check in this function (and I should, you're right) but what's happening is that before customer.FavoriteProducts.Remove(product) is called the list of FavoriteProducts contains the product to be removed and after customer.FavoriteProducts.Remove(product) is called it does not. The total count is 1 less as well. It is working in my code. The problem is absolutely happening somewhere during the SaveChanges() call. There could be a problem in my code somewhere but the fact that it works fine from my local computer against the same database baffles me.

Comment: I'm not an expert at working with database logs. What would i look for if I tried going through them. Is it possible the problem might show up there?

Answer (score -1):

Try the following in your `AddProductToCustomer` method:

```
_context.Entry(customer).State = EntityState.Modified;
_context.SaveChanges();
```